# Efficiently computing size of filtered list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to efficiently compute the size of a filtered list, i.e., I don't want to keep the whole filtered list in memory, I just want to get its size. Is there a more "pythonic" way than computing the size using a for-loop?

For example:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]

# this loads the entire **filtered** list in memory
size_of_filtered_list = len([item for item in my_list if item % 2 == 0])

# is there a more pythonic way than this?
size_of_filtered_list = 0
for item in my_list:
    if item % 2 == 0:
        size_of_filtered_list += 1
```

**UPDATE**

Apologies if I was not clear. Although the first list (e.g., my_list) is already in memory, I don't want to create an extra list containing the filtered elements just to count them. I knew about generators and sum but just did not connect the dots... Thanks for your answers.

Comment: "this loads the entire list in memory I believe"?  All lists are always in memory all the time.  What's the point?

Comment: Looks like `quantify`. http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes

Comment: @S.Lott: I think he means that he wants what the size would be IF he created the list -- see his "for loop".

Comment: @John Machin:  In the `for` example, `my_list` is a proper list, entirely in memory.  I don't get the question.

Comment: @KennyTM thanks for the pointer to quantify. Actually, quantify seems to be a lot slower than all of the other solutions (generator with 1, generator with True, len(filtered_list)). It's strange given the comment at the top of the examples: "High speed is retained by preferring “vectorized” building blocks over the use of for-loops and generators which incur interpreter overhead."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
size_of_filtered_list = sum(1 for item in my_list if item % 2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
size_of_filtered_list = sum(item%2==0 for item in my_list)
```

Comment: that creates list doesn't it?

Comment: @SilentGhost: no it doesn't the generator expression is lazy, however gnibbler's solution will be slightly faster, as it is both lazy and sum() wouldn't need to add the zeros.

Comment: @Lie: you don't seem to be new here, but [anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3976880/revisions)

Comment: @lie, i was using list comprehension earlier. I changed my answer as i misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: @ghostdog74 Thanks for your answer. It's readable and looks like what I needed, but I believe (according to my tests) that it is slightly less efficient than gnibbler's answer because the sum has to go through all elements of the filtered list (0+1+0+1) instead of (1+1)

Comment: speed is the least I thought of when i created the answer. I like it to be shorter than gnibbler's. Its entirely up to you to choose the best for your needs.